# Launch intent inside method run through reflection

Tags: android, android-intent, reflection

Inside the Configuration activity I have two controls that are calling the same method. Here is the method:

```
public void goDetection() {     
        Intent detection = new Intent(this, Detection.class);
        startActivity(detection);
    }
```

This method is executed from a basic button click and it works fine.
The same method should also be executed inside an AlertDialog, as method associated to the "positiveButton".
I invoke this method to the "positiveButton"'s onClick handler as this:

```
try {
    Method method = Configuration.class.getMethod(methodPositive);
    Object obj = new Configuration(); 
    method.invoke(obj);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    Log.d("There is an error in Configuration class: NoSuchMethodException", e.getMessage());
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    Log.d("There is an error in Configuration class: IllegalAccessException", e.getMessage());
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Log.d("There is an error in Configuration class: IllegalArgumentException", e.getMessage());
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    Log.d("There is an error in Configuration class: InvocationTargetException", e.getMessage());
}
```

where methodPositive = "goDetection".
Using a Log.d() insertion in the goDetection() method I find that the method gets started, but there is an error when executing the

```
startActivity(detection);
```

statement. From LogCat the first application-code-related error is  "NullPointerException: println needs a message" in the above statement:

```
catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    Log.d("There is an error in Configuration class: InvocationTargetException", e.getMessage());
}
```

It's not the first time I use this mechanism but it's the first time I get stuck. What am I missing?
Many thanks!

Comment: more code needed. somewhere you are printing or logging an input value thats not being set.

Comment: I print nothing and the only values I'm logging are in the catch sections, all e.getMessage()

Comment: wrong, "NullPointerException: println needs a message"

Comment: I know, that's why is weird. If I comment the "startActivity(detection)" statement there is no error ... but the Intent is not launched

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure it's the InvocationTargetException as failure reason. Any knwolodge around that is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
One should invoke this object

```
Object obj = Configuration.this;
```

rather than the one I used

```
Object obj = new Configuration();
```

The system got fooled because it didn't know where the alert box was associated to!